# Azure Devops - Test plans - Test case association to automated tests

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My team are using test plans for manual testing, We also have a suite of automated tests which we would like to store in test plans and associate to the automated tests so that when the automated tests run, the test case results in test plans gets updated automatically.

We are currently creating a test case in test to represent each automated test. We then associate the automated test in visual studio, to the test case ID in test plans.

Whilst this approach works, we have a few hundred automated tests and counting.
Doing it this involves a lot of manual effort and is prone to human error.

Does anyone know of a quicker way to copy the automated tests from visual studio to test plans and associate them with the test case ID's

Comment: Hi @bobe_b, Have you got a chance to test with the suggested rest API below? With the help of this API, we can programmatically associate test assemblies with test cases.

Comment: hi no not yet but thanks for the reply...so you need to use the example call for each individual test that you want to link?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use this [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) to update the `Associated Automation` of test cases instead of using VS.

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=7.1-preview.3

[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestName",
    "value": "[namespace.classname.methodname (e.g. AzureWebAppDotNetCore.Tests.ProgramTests.AddTest)]"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestStorage",
    "value": "[assembly name (e.g. AzureWebAppDotNetCoreTests.dll)]"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestType",
    "value": "Unit Test"
  }
]
```

Taking my demo below for example, the test case`#838 AddTest` was not associated with any automated test. I used the API to associate the test assembly from my code with this test case in my test suite `#839`of the test plan `#836`.

[image]

I could then proceed to run the automated test in the pipeline, which then updated the result to the associated test case.
[image]